# Achieving DI without 3rd party framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am writing a plugin as part of a plugin architecture.  The way plugins are created is via reflection and `CreateInstance`.  Therefore the default constructor is called. This code I cannot touch and I am trying to find a sensible way to use DI without the ability to use a framework.

I believe I have 3 options:

i) Poor Man's DI (PMDI)

ii) Factory Pattern

iii) TinyIOC or similar (one cs file that handles DI)

I started looking at PMDI but then a dependency needed another dependency so I ended up with something similar to this which is ugly and could get worse:

```
public MyMainPluginClass() : this(new Repo(new Logger()))
{

}

public MyMainPluginClass(IRepo repo)
{

}
```

I then moved onto the idea of a Factory Pattern but could not find any decent demo code. I assume I would have something like this:

```
public static FactoryUtility
{
  public static IRepo GetRepo()
  {
    return new Repo(GetLogger());
  }

  public static ILogger GetLogger()
  {
    return new Logger();
  }
}

    public MyMainPluginClass() : this(FactoryUtility.GetRepo())
    {

    }

    public MyMainPluginClass(IRepo repo)
    {

    }
```

Is that how it would look?

I then came across [TinyIOC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC) which is one class that does all the dependency registering  but I believe it requires to be setup in a Program.cs which I don't have in a class library. If someone has any experience using this could it be used like so:

```
    public MyMainPluginClass()
    {
       var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;
       container.AutoRegister();
       var implementation = container.Resolve<IRepo>();

       MyMainPluginClass(implementation);
    }

    public MyMainPluginClass(IRepo repo)
    {

    }
```

Are there any alternative approaches to achieve DI without using a 3rd party library and if not which approach would choose from above?

**NOTE:** The code above has not been compiled and is just an idea of what I think would work. Please post corrections if they are valid approaches.

Comment: Just FYI; your 3rd code example is also basically poor mans dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with TinyIOC in the end. Unfortunately the plugin's constructor gets called several times before its actually up and running. I simply set a boolean to prevent registration being called several times and therefore it allows me to simply auto-register dependencies and off we go.

```
public MyMainPluginClass() : this(FactoryUtility.SetupIOC())
{

}

public MyMainPluginClass(IRepo repo)
{

}

public static class FactoryUtility
{
    private static bool Initialized  = false;

    public static IRepo SetupIOC()
    {
        var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;

        if (!Initialized)
        {
            container.AutoRegister(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });

            Initialized = true;
        }

        var result = container.Resolve<IRepo>();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using .NET 4, you might want to consider using MEF, as it's built into the framework itself.  This looks like fairly straightforward DI, which MEF handles well, as it's intended mainly for extensibility.

For details, see the [Learn More page on the MEF CodePlex site](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Overview&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: I cannot use MEF as this is a legacy product with its own architecture

Comment: @Jon If you're implementing the DI portion, you can use anything you want... The fact that the main application won't use it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Do you have an example of using a legacy architecture looking for a plugin that inherits a certain base class with MEF?

Comment: @Jon I don't - you'd have to just add the `[Export]` attributes to your implementation class, ie: `[Export(typeof(LegacyProject.BaseClass)]` - and then import the appropriate type anywhere as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I absolutely don't want to add a dependency to a DI container, I like to use my own TinyIOC (sorry about the name, didn't know it was taken), which for small projects gives me the same semantics as using a container, but clocks in at below 200 LOC.

If you are interested, here is the code: https://gist.github.com/ad7608e2ae10b0f04229

Comment: Would this be setup in my default constructor and could I then call another constructor with a resolved type?

Comment: The Ioc part of an app usually lives in the infrastructure of your app. At certain neuralgic points of your app, a container is asked for an instance and it is at that moment that dependencies are resolved. Above code also has the notion of a container.

Comment: I agree but as I have mentioned I cannot touch the original app and do not have a program.cs to setup the IOC Container

Comment: But something calls some part of your code, right? From your perspective, that would be the entry point, and from there on you could use Ioc-pieces...

Comment: The entry point is the constructor. The main app uses reflection to find DLL's and if it finds a match it calls CreateInstance which calls the constructor.  That class then may have dependencies which in turn has dependencies. Will setting up the IOC in the constructor work?

Comment: I've just tried your Gist, thank you but now I'm getting confused with how that is any different from a factory method. You could argue setting up any IOC for DI could be done with a factory method so this may be getting into deep debate time!